# How do I got annotations from base Object in UIComponent?

Tags: java, jsf-2, annotations, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

Update: I've update my question to clear what I do.

I'm trying update some legancy code of my work. I'm using JSF validation 
and I want use JSR-303/349 with annotations on entities.

I use generated html with jQuery code to make these validations work on client side and because that I cant't just put annotations on entities. Here is a sample of my TextRenderer code:

```
import com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TextRenderer;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.context.ResponseWriter;
import javax.faces.context.ResponseWriterWrapper;

public class UiRender extends TextRenderer {
    @Override
    protected void getEndTextToRender(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String currentValue)
        throws IOException {
      if (component instanceof UIInput) {
        final UIInput uiInput = (UIInput) component;
        final ResponseWriter originalResponseWriter = context.getResponseWriter();
        context.setResponseWriter(new ResponseWriterWrapper() {

          @Override
          public ResponseWriter getWrapped() {
            return originalResponseWriter;
          }

          @Override
          public void startElement(String name, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
            super.startElement(name, component);
            super.writeAttribute("required", uiInput.isRequired(), null); //<- here i got required attribute
            super.writeAttribute("requiredMessage", uiInput.getRequiredMessage(), null);//<- here i got requiredMessage
          }
        });

        super.getEndTextToRender(context, component, currentValue);
        context.setResponseWriter(originalResponseWriter); // Restore original writer.
      }
    }
}
```

To use this render, I can use "required" and "requiredMessage" attritube on "inputText" tag. 
For exemple:

```
    <h:inputText id="field" 
            value="#{bean.myObject.field}" 
            required="true"
            requiredMessage="Field is required" />
```

This render a html like this:

And, before do action, I can use a jQuery code like this:

```
    function validateInputTextWithRequiredAttribute() {
      var msg = '';
      $('input:visible[required="required"]').each(
              function () {
                if ($(this).val() === '') {
                  msg += $(this).attr("requiredmessage") + '<br/>'
                }
              }
      );
      if (msg) {
        showErrorMessage(msg);
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
```

I want to use Bean Validation to have class MyObject like this:

```
public class MyObject{
    @NotNull SomeField field;
}
```

Is there any easy way to get @NotNull information on UiRender or to know if "SomeField" has NotNull attribute?

I'm using:

- com.sun.faces.jsf-impl version: 2.2.10;
- org.hibernate.hibernate-validator version: 4.3.2.Final
- javax.validation.validation-api version: 1.1.0.Final

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking here. Can you clarify your question? And what do you mean with "We are using JSR-303/349 validators on xhtml pages". How would that work?

Comment: @Hardy, I tried clarify my question. Sorry my bad english.